# bash array fail to store multiple file names

Tags: bash

I have the following two files:

```
> ls *.ccs.bam
m54105_171201_020331.ccs.bam  m54105_171201_121745.ccs.bam
```

Unfortunately, I fail to safe them in array:

```
> shopt -s nullglob
> ccs_bams=(*.ccs.bam)
> echo $ccs_bams
m54105_171201_020331.ccs.bam
```

Why does only one file gets printed?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *storing* all the names, but you are only accessing the 0th one. From `man bash`:

```
   Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to ref‐
   erencing  the array with a subscript of 0.
```

To reference *all* elements of the array, as separate words, use `"${ccs_bams[@]}"` ex.

```
printf '%s\n' "${ccs_bams[@]}"
```